# ld is unresponsive to both LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: compilation

I'm working on a shared CentOS server where I don't have root.

```
cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)
```

I recently updated my GCC/G++ version to 9.4.0, but now all of my C++ builds are failing at the linking step. I've tracked down the issue to the fact that `ld` is looking for libraries in directories that I haven't told it to and picking up old versions of `libstdc++` that I can't get rid of. Moreover, it seems to be completely unresponsive to both `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH`.

```
-bash-4.2$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/public/users/jeizenga/.local/lib:/public/users/jeizenga/.local/lib64
-bash-4.2$ export LIBRARY_PATH=/public/users/jeizenga/.local/lib:/public/users/jeizenga/.local/lib64
-bash-4.2$ ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR | tr -s ' ;' '\n'
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/local/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/lib64")=
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/local/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/lib")
```

What am I missing here? Everything I've found so far has suggested using these environment variables to solve the problem, but that's not working for me.

Comment: Add the output of `echo $LIBRARY_PATH` and `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the question.

Comment: check ld.so.conf and ld.so.conf.d

Comment: @NasirRiley the `echo`s give what you'd expect from the `export` statement.

@stark from the contents of `ls.so.conf` are `include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf` and `ls /etc/ld.so.conf.d/` gives a bunch of `.conf` files. I'm not quite sure how to interpret these though.